# How can I hide/remove the "Top Results" section when searching in my mails in the Microsoft Outlook web interface (OWA)?

Tags: outlook-365

How can I hide/remove the "Top Results" section when searching in my  mails in the Microsoft Outlook web interface (OWA)?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One can disable the "Top Results" section when searching in one's mail as follows:

Go to https://outlook.office.com/mail/options/general/search and uncheck `Show top three most relevant results`:

[image]

[image]

Thanks [Joe P](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/users/293987/joe-p) for [pointing me](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/115704/how-can-i-hide-remove-the-top-results-section-when-searching-in-my-mails-in-th/164007#comment150398_115704) to that setting.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think you can.  There are eight pages of negative comments from people having exactly this problem [here](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook_com/forum/oemail-osearch/removing-top-results-from-search-in-outlook-owa/871d1474-8d20-40e0-9233-ea827acfb639).

Answer (score 1):

You still can't turn it off.  Microsoft sent me this link today so that I could "Vote to have it looked into".  https://outlook.uservoice.com/forums/284136-outlook-com/suggestions/32166424-create-option-to-remove-top-results-from-search-in

Answer (score -1):

It is possible turn off the "Top Result" option in outlook. From file go to "options" then select "search" and uncheck the "Show most relevant search results on top" option

Comment: Them, is it for the Outlook desktop program or web interface?